# ASP MVC UrlHelper.Action - high memory allocations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

After enabling [Azure's Optimization Insights](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability-blog/announcing-the-limited-preview-of-optimization-insights/ba-p/3254582) feature on a web app, the majority of its reports are **Excessive allocations due to UrlHelper.Action**

Given MVC5 is a bit long in the tooth at this point, are there any further speedups/workarounds to `UrlHelper.Action` other than just not using it at all and generating URLs to action methods manually?

[image]

Comment: Bumping this on GitHub at: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/382

Comment: Did you ever figure out whats happening? I have a fairly complex application that im trying to optimize and I found this too - which is extremely surprising.

Comment: @franknavarrete will need to dig into the source code. I filed a bug with Microsoft but the project is just too old for them to be concerned.